# How to use ECG graph in Windows mobile 8.1 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

Guys I am working on a project in which i want to use some graphs. is there any library to make ECG graphs in windows mobile 8.1 application and WPF Application?? I searched on google but i didnt get any help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try too look into Line Chart (LineSeries) from:
[WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.Controls.DataVisualization)

For me, it's the best free library for drawing graphs in XAML. Also I think this article with examples will be useful for you [Using graphs and charts in windows store apps](http://eren.ws/2013/10/15/using-graphs-and-charts-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-11/).